# Laravel - Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.7 and... well, this error is happening because of a library that i am using right now: [highideas/laravel-users-online](https://github.com/highideas/laravel-users-online) in which this function:

```
public function setCache($minutes = 5)
    {
        return Cache::put($this->getCacheKey(), $this->getCacheContent(), $minutes);
    }
```

Throws the next error:

```
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

The two functions that it uses are:

```
public function getCacheContent()
    {
        if (!empty($cache = Cache::get($this->getCacheKey()))) {
            return $cache;
        }
        $cachedAt = Carbon::now();
        return [
            'cachedAt' => $cachedAt,
            'user' => $this,
        ];
    }
```

And:

```
public function getCacheKey()
    {
        return sprintf('%s-%s', "UserOnline", $this->id);
    }
```

Is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: What's in here `$this->getCacheContent()`? `Cache::put('key', 'value', $min);` requires second parameter to be string

Comment: The code of that function is in my question

Comment: The ``FileStore.php`` file says that the second parameter "value" is a mixed, not a string

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that. It's returning an array, however the required parameter should be string. You can try `serialize($this->getCacheContent())` to convert array to string

Comment: Let me try that!

Comment: It doesn't work, it throws the exact same error

Comment: `return Cache::put($this->getCacheKey(), serialize($this->getCacheContent()), $minutes);` - because `getCacheContent()` returns an array, you should store strings

Comment: `Cache::put` will already call `serialize` internally. I suspect issue is related to the `user` variable, which contains some data which cannot be automatically serialized.

Comment: It was the user variable! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Instead of `'user' => $this,` why not `'user' => auth()->user()->toArray(),`?